# Give user acces to component without authentification

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am beginner in salesforce developer  so right now i am trying to implement some feature for my company : some question and has some answer (like Salesforce survey)  i try to make  this component visible for public without authentication  i found a ways in Visualforce but for lightning didn't found a specific way should i go to visualforce ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_creating.htm&type=5), then put the components on to a Page within the Community. No authentication is required to make this work.

Comment: i have create a site and add "implements = allowGuestUser and she work fine for me right now so thanks .